# MySQL error code 1064 when using distinct

Tags: mysql

I just began studying MySQL and ran into error 1064.
It's a basic and short snippet.
Please help, I've tried googling for about an hour now.
I come to you as a last resort.

```
select  distinct(b.publisher), c.name
from  customer c, orders o, book b
where c.name = 'Park' and
c.custid = o.custid and b.bookid = o.bookid;
```

My question is that while above code works, if I put c.name in front of distinct(b.publisher), I get a 1064. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of DISTINCT is to eliminates doubles rows, meaning the exact same data in all your returned columns.

If you have several columns in your SELECT clause, you can NOT have DISTINCT on one column only. And this is the reason of your error 1064

Thus you should do either

```
select  distinct b.publisher, c.name
```

or

```
select  distinct b.publisher
```

which is the exact same as

```
select  distinct(b.publisher)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm trying to select your answer as the answer but cannot find a button to do it. Also, I can edit what you've written, is that normal?